# How to convert timedelta in data frame to datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have couple columns in df with avg time, example "0 days 00:00:21". I want convert all columns to datetime.time format "hh:mm:ss" without "0 days". How can I do this?

[my df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8kDU.png)

Comment: You can't convert a timedelta to a datetime (that simply doesn't make sense). Do you actually have `datetime.timedelta` objects in the DF? What's your end goal here with the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fine with that code

For 4 columns, u can create a list of column names that u want to change. After that, put into for loop to iterate all column names that u want to change. It'll convert columns.

```
column_names = ["first","second","third","fourth"]

for name in column_names:
    df[name] = df[name].dt.seconds.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').time())
```

Comment: it's working but only for one column, i have in my df 9 columns and i need change 4 columns and leave the rest unchanged

Comment: can u sent your all table so I can take look according that. @GrzegorzZ

Comment: I attached an image in the first message

Comment: @GrzegorzZ I changed code, u can put your column names which u want to change into column_names list and it will convert all your columns

Comment: it's working :-) maybe you know why I'm getting the message? "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @GrzegorzZ  to avoid that problem u can use `df.loc[:, name] = df[name].dt.total_seconds().apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').time())` can u try this.

Comment: pandas indicates that modifications are being attempted on a temporary subset of the DataFrame rather than the original DataFrame so best option is the use .loc. Also I'd appreciate you considering upvote and/or accepting this solution if it helped you. @GrzegorzZ

Comment: i find    `zd.loc[:,name]`

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you data is stored.. but you could try something like this:

```
# Example DataFrame
data = {'time1': ['0 days 00:00:21', '0 days 00:01:15', '0 days 00:02:45'],
        'time2': ['0 days 00:00:35', '0 days 00:00:50', '0 days 00:03:10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert columns to timedelta objects
df[['time1', 'time2']] = df[['time1', 'time2']].apply(pd.to_timedelta)

# Extract time component and convert to string
df[['time1', 'time2']] = df[['time1', 'time2']].applymap(lambda x: x.seconds)

# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format
df[['time1', 'time2']] = df[['time1', 'time2']].applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s').time())

print(df)`
```

Comment: my df have 9 columns:       
dtypes: int32(1), int64(3), object(2), timedelta64[ns](4). 
"unit='s' not valid with non-numerical val='0 days 00:00:21', at position 0 "

Comment: what data type is the avg time value?

Comment: timedelta64[ns]

Comment: ok, you need to provide a reproducible data in a format I can see.

Comment: I attached an image in the first message